# HTML dialog element "cancel" event not firing when press tab before interacting with it

Tags: javascript

> (!) The following behavior is only happening in Chrome as far as I am concerned.

In the following snippet, you can see the cancel event is not always firing.

If you open the dialog, then immediately press the escape key, then only the "close" event is fired.

If you open the dialog, then interact with it anyhow by for example tabbing in it or clicking on it, then you press the escape key, then the "cancel" event is fired followed by the "close" event.

```js
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
const open = document.getElementById("open");
const close = document.getElementById("close");

open.addEventListener("click", () => dialog.showModal());

close.addEventListener("click", () => dialog.close());

dialog.addEventListener("cancel", () => console.log("cancel"));

dialog.addEventListener("close", () => console.log("close"));
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog">
  <p>click here before escaping</p>
  <button id="close">close</button>
</dialog>
<button id="open">open</button>
```

This is a problem for me because the "cancel" event is always desirable so I know when the dialog was closed by the browser. You can see why in the second snippet where I need to play my own custom close method when closing the dialog.

When the browser closes my dialog through screen reader actions, the escape key, or other means, it will call the dialog elements close method instead of my class's close method. By using the cancel event, we can fix this issue, however, this is depended on the cancel event actually firing, hence my problem.

```js
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
const open = document.getElementById("open");
const close = document.getElementById("close");

class Dialog {
  constructor(options) {
  
    this.dialog = options.dialog;
    options.open.addEventListener("click", () => this.open());
    options.close.addEventListener("click", () => this.close());
    
    this.dialog.addEventListener("cancel", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.close();
    });
    
  }
  open() {
    this.dialog.showModal();
  }
  close() {
    this.dialog.classList.add("closeAnimation");
    this.dialog.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
        this.dialog.close();
        this.dialog.classList.remove("closeAnimation");
    }, { once: true });
  }
}

new Dialog({dialog, open, close});
```

```css
dialog.closeAnimation {
  animation: fade-out 500ms forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog">
  <p>Click here to before escape</p>
  <button id="close">close</button>
</dialog>
<button id="open">open</button>
```

My question is if anyone knows a way to always trigger the cancel event. I tried the following when opening the dialog but it didn't work:

```
const defaultFocus = document.activeElement;
this.dialog.click();
defaultFocus.focus();
```

How can I make the dialog be considered "interacted with" so it fires cancel?

Comment: Only thing I can think of would be to add a flag to my class which is only set when my class's close method is called. Then I can listen to the element's onclose event and if the flag is not set, then reopen the dialog and call the class's close method. I don't like this solution, but I guess it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Add an "keydown" event listener to the the dialog just as like you did for "cancel" inside constructor:

```
constructor(options) {
    this.dialog.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        const key = event.key; // Or const {key} = event; in ES6+
        if (key === "Escape") {
          e.preventDefault();
          this.close();
        }
    });
    ...
```

But i would suggest not messing with events like this since is not that easy to keep track of what events are you defining in the whole code. Instead you could implement each function/method and call it on the desired class instace.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The problem is that the close method from my class is not being called at all when you press the escape key because the browser by default will just use the element's close method instead of my class's close method

Comment: Yes, you are correct, i misunderstood. I've just edited the answer, see if it fits you!